# Apache Camel. Base configuration for all routes

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have a lot of routes for which  need to add general error handling and do some actions, such as logging, adding information (headers), etc. I do this in runtime now that gather all the routes from the camel context and delete them and instead new RouteBuilders are added with all the necessary actions. But it takes for a very long time to start, because you need to **stop, delete, add and start** new routes. Is there any way to solve this problem in more efficient way?

One of the options for me is transforming xml files, but may be there is an option through **Java dsl**.
maybe camel 3.0 can solve this?

Comment: Not sure what you exactly mean, though using a parent `RouteBuilder` that defines all of your exception handling and inheriting from this is what we basically do all the time. Just make sure that you invoke `super.configure()` in your child route builders in case you override the `configure()` method of the base route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you already looked at Camel's [intersept](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/intercept.html) feature?
Using it you could for example add a custom header to every Exchange in your routes

```
<interceptFrom uri="*">
    <setHeader headerName="specific"><simple>42</simple></setHeader>
</interceptFrom>
```

Answering to the rest of your question, to configure general error handling and logging you have an option of using `onException` and `onCompletion` blocks, which would be applied for every route in the CamelContext they were provided

Comment: Thank you. i will try it. I would want to clarify that intercept works during execution of route or you can pre-implement this behavior in route so that there is no unnecessary load.

Comment: it intercepts Exchanges while they are on route, so the desired behavior will being added at the runtime. Conversely, the `onException` and `onCompletion` sections will be add to every route configuration when Camel is started